# Kernel 4.13.0-38 unable to solve Errata error. unable to install intel-microcode

Tags: drivers, kernel

I have landed up in a strange problem with kernel 4.13.0-38.

The problem which I have is similar to the kernel bug [reference link](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/virtualbox/+bug/1736116?comments=all). But the difference is that I am not running in VM.

```
System details

aravind@comp:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial

aravind@comp:~$ uname -r
4.13.0-38-generic

Laptop Acer E15 E5-575G-50ZZ
Inter core i5-7200U
Nvidia GeForce 940MX
```

If I have intel-microcode installed in my system. Then my login screen freeze and unable to login.

If I remove the driver it works file but I am getting error in the log,

```
[Firmware Bug]: TSC_DEADLINE disabled due to Errata; please update microcode to version: 0x52 (or later)
```

If I check the package details. I found it has a conflict:

```
aravind@comp:~$ dpkg -s intel-microcode
Package: intel-microcode
Status: deinstall ok config-files
Priority: standard
Section: non-free/admin
Installed-Size: 1530
Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
Architecture: amd64
Version: 3.20180312.0~ubuntu16.04.1
Config-Version: 3.20180312.0~ubuntu16.04.1
Depends: iucode-tool (>= 1.0)
Recommends: initramfs-tools (>= 0.113~)
Conflicts: microcode.ctl (<< 0.18~0)
Conffiles:
 /etc/default/intel-microcode 6a68a0e6e2d2ef001f1a374ece3c8558
 /etc/kernel/preinst.d/intel-microcode 4324b7d12701909b3a76bb5c6468a571
 /etc/modprobe.d/intel-microcode-blacklist.conf 71327241f6583b34944e638a955aba91
Description: Processor microcode firmware for Intel CPUs
 This package contains updated system processor microcode for
 Intel i686 and Intel X86-64 processors.  Intel releases microcode
 updates to correct processor behavior as documented in the
 respective processor specification updates.
 .
 For AMD processors, please refer to the amd64-microcode package.
Homepage: https://downloadcenter.intel.com/search?keyword=linux+microcode
Original-Maintainer: Henrique de Moraes Holschuh <hmh@debian.org>
```

Now how to find the reason for conflict and solve this error?

Additional note: That same configuration works fine when I boot from kernel version 4.13.0-28

Comment: The solution to this issue is that to install update of kernel 4.13.0-39 & install intel-microcode.